# Firebird jdbc connection error: no suitable Driver instance

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, firebird, spring-jdbc

When I'm trying to connect db with Java application, I'm facing below error.

caused by: java.lang.runtimeexception: failed to get driver instance for jdbcurl=jdbc:firebirdsql://veddb.floor:3050/c:\mydb\aryan\ved.fdb

I have tried multiple jars with dependencies but still not working.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], and include the full exception stacktrace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to unzip the directory where is jar file and then add it as dependencies. If not working please provide more information.